# Can LINQ handle a Has-Many-Through relationship (and how is it done)?

Tags: c#, linq

I come from a Ruby on Rails background and am new to Linq. It has been pretty easy to setup Has-Many relationships with most of my models using this method:

```
public class Person
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID;
    [Column]
    public string Name;

    [Association(Storage = "Carts", ThisKey = "CartID")] // Let's assume this exists
    public EntitySet<Cart> Items
    {
        get { return this._Carts; }
        set { this._Carts.Assign(value); }
    }
    private EntitySet<Cart> _Carts = new EntitySet<Cart>();
}
```

And this let's me do something like:

```
foreach (Cart cart in person.carts)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

But let's say `Cart` has access to another entity set called `Items`, currently I am having to do this:

```
foreach (Cart cart in person.carts)
{
    foreach (Item item in cart.items)
    {
       // Do stuff
    }
}
```

**Can I / How do I setup `Cart` so that I can do this:**

```
foreach (Item item in person.carts.items)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` to flatten a sequence of sequences:

```
foreach (Item item in person.carts.SelectMany(cart => cart.items))
{
}
```